# MongoDB: Update a document node at unknown depth in hierarchical structure

Tags: c#, mongodb

Given a document with the structure depicted by the JSON below, I need to know if I can update field values on a single node where all I know is the value of the forum post '_id' field, and the master document id.

Note that the document contains an array of forum posts, each of which can contain nested forum posts, in atree type structure. I need to be able to modify nested forum posts in a "*Update any descendant which has a property '_id' matching X*" fashion.

I'm currently thinking I could pull the document and recursively search in the application layer for the node with the corresponding '_id' value, and then construct a query for updating the node having discovered the node depth.

I'm wondering if there is a better way though. Does MongoDB have any built in functionality for querying nodes at unknown depth within a document? If there is, can I use this to update the field values on that node?

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5553555ca077e61d64d0ef27"),
  "ThreadTitle" : "Test Post",
  "Upvotes" : 0,
  "CreatedMemberId" : 123,
  "ForumPosts" : [{
      "_id" : "75e9b53a-0358-4b17-8969-592eac36c294",
      "Upvotes" : 2,
      "CreatedMemberId" : 123,
      "PostText" : "This is some test post text",
      "PostImages" : null,
      "SubForumPosts" : [{
          "_id" : "5f1c8d4b-8258-4290-9de1-f5e0c0971915",
          "Upvotes" : 2,
          "CreatedMemberId" : 456,
          "PostText" : "This is some test post text from 456",
          "PostImages" : null,
          "SubForumPosts" : [{
              "_id" : "2956ca8f-2890-4eca-a3b2-2595a7b8c3ad",
              "Upvotes" : 2,
              "CreatedMemberId" : 123,
              "PostText" : "This is some test post text from 123",
              "PostImages" : null,
              "SubForumPosts" : null
            }, {
              "_id" : "8d105548-f82a-4cd5-8f6c-b34b1ce273ee",
              "Upvotes" : 4,
              "CreatedMemberId" : 789,
              "PostText" : "This is some test post text from 789",
              "PostImages" : null,
              "SubForumPosts" : null
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Currently mongo does not has any built in way to do this. I ran into this problem before when storing hierarchal data myself. I originally wrote a recursive function to traverse the tree, modify the document, and update the entire doc. It was incredibly slow depending on depth and the code just looked awful. I eventually used the ancestor pattern from mongo http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-ancestors-array/

Comment: Thanks. Given that the relationships are not fixed values (i.e. forum post ids and not categories), none of the model tree structures documented on the MongoDB site seem to fit unfortunately.

Comment: the actual ancestor value that you store does not matter. I use ObjectId in my ancestor array for my data and it has worked fine. you are just modeling in the document what it's ancestors are which can be stored as the ObjectId

Comment: Just interpret your data as (directed acyclic) graph with 'shapeless' objects. That way, you can essentially store any data structure. Having many different writers access a single document is recipe for disaster, even if it were possible with the query language.

Comment: @ThrowsException, actually yes, I see that now. If I record every ancestor in an array in the "Model Tree Structures with an Array of Ancestors", this looks more feasible. Thanks.